# Dom get child node from curl response

Tags: curl, dom

Earlier i am getting class from url by using following code

```
    $dom  = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    @$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
    $finder        = new DOMXPath($dom);
    //Get Element By Class Name
    $childNodeList = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");
    return $childNodeList;
```

and i am getting output

> DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 30 )

Now i want to get the same output but inspite of url i want to use curl response in dom.

Comment: check CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, and note that DOMDocument::loadHTML can take both an url (as you're using it), and a string of HTML directly (which you'll get from curl)

Comment: @hanshenrik Thanks